# MySQL link two tables together implicitly

Tags: mysql

Suppose we have two tables

A table called **people** with people linked to a bank account balances

```
| id | name | account_id |
--------------------------
| 1  | bob  | 11         |
--------------------------
| 2  | sam  | 22
```

A table called **accounts** with bank account balances

```
| id | value |
--------------
| 11 | 200   |
--------------
| 22 | 500   |
```

In order to link the two tables you can do

```
SELECT a.value as account_balance 
FROM people p 
WHERE p.name="bob" 
LEFT JOIN accounts a ON p.account_id = a.id`
```

This would return

```
id => 1
name => bob
account_balance => 200
```

That's cool - but I am wondering if there is a more implicit way to do this via SQL linkage (foreign keys or otherwise). Can we in MySQL add links in some other way so that when we do a SELECT, it already knows to return **value** instead of **account_id **?

I'm asking this because I am creating a system where my users can create lookup tables and link them to other tables - but it must be do-able without any programming. The only other way I can think of is to set the name of **account_id** for example to **accounts.value** and treat that as a foreign key when doing a SELECT.

I would have to get the column structure and analyze and then determine that there is a foreign key and then return the appropriate foreign column by looking at the column name.

Comment: I advice a book on databases.

Comment: Nice. An easy one. No.

Comment: Users who don't have any programming training should not be permitted to create tables in the database. This is a recipe for certain disaster.